# Javascript parsing URL using parseURL function

Tags: javascript, parsing, url

I am trying to write code to parse URL using Javascript parseURL function

Input are some of the URL

```
1.http://www.cnn.com/index.html
2.https://yahoo.com/movies/index.html?refresh=1
```

Expected Output

```
1.http,www.cnn.com
2.https,yahoo.com,refresh=1
```

I have tried to write code

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var stdin = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function parse(chunk) {
  stdin += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
  var lines = stdin.trim().split('\n');
  for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    process.stdout.write(lines[i]);
  }
});
```

But I am unable to get expected output

Comment: Have you considered using the standard `url` package that's built-into node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `/^.+(?=:\/\/)|(?<=:\/\/)[^\/]+|(?<=\?).+$/g` enumerates the following three possibilities, matching any of them with alternation:

1. the beginning of the string up until `://`
2. `://` until the next `/`
3. everything after a `?` until the end of the string.

```js
const pattern = /^.+(?=:\/\/)|(?<=:\/\/)[^\/]+|(?<=\?).+$/g;
[
  "1.http://www.cnn.com/index.html",
  "2.https://yahoo.com/movies/index.html?refresh=1"
].forEach(e => console.log(e.match(pattern)));
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, could you please help me  figure out where should I add this in my code? What changes should I make in the code? Thank you

Comment: Hard to say--it looks like you're returning an object with 4 properties, but only 2-3 appear in your split strings. You'll need to provide more information, but basically you have an array of 2-3 elements and can assign them to your object properties as you wish.

Comment: Okay I have edited the code, could you suggest where should I add your code? In the end I just want a seperate String

Comment: Is each `chunk` a single line? If so, you can put the code in the listener. Or, take all the input, then operate on the result string `s`. Split it by lines and use the regex on each line as I'm doing. Again, it's hard to say, because I don't know what your stdin is accepting. But basically, that's all boilerplate--just show what `s` and/or `chunk` looks like exactly and there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Yes each chunk is a single line

Comment: All right, `chunk.match(pattern)` should be sufficient if the chunks are equivalent to the lines matching the format you posted and I used in my example. Push the result onto an array or do whatever you like with it.